# mod_rewrite cause errors in apache error.log

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In Opencart I have enabled SEO URLS, which is working fine, unless that I see errors in apache log:

> `[Thu Apr 16 22:53:38 2015] [error] [client xy] File does not exist: /home/html/xy.eu/public_html/duse, referer: http://xy.eu/duse/`

Is this a mod_rewrite related problem?

Here is the relevant htaccess which I use from OC:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Full source:
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/.htaccess.txt

Comment: I do not know OpenCart, but I do not see a reference in your .htaccess that would effect your issue.

Comment: mod_rewrite won't cause this. Assuming your URLs are being correctly rewritten, then your server would seem to be (for some reason) writing the log entry _before_ mod_rewrite has rewritten the URL. Presumably this is completely flooding your logs?

Answer (score 1):

As you state that the SEO friendly URL's are working fine then that means that mod_rewrite is working fine. For some reason your Apache server is doing the logging prior to the rewrite rules being executed. The only time I have seen this before was with a glitch in Apache and the only fix I was able to find for it was to reinstall Apache from scratch!